# Clean toshiba a300d 14r

Tags: laptop, fan, cleaning

i'm not able to open my notebook, a **toshiba a300d-14r**.

Googling i don't find any useful information...

*This is official site*:
http://it.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/jsp/SUPPORTSECTION/discontinuedProductPage.do?service=IT&PRODUCT_ID=1056713&DISC_MODEL=1#0

Anyone have an idea to open it. The fan goes crazy when power on and i suppose that is full of dusty.
**I need to clean the fan...**

Is there a **guide** or a **useful information** to do it?

thanks,
A

Comment: This question should be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: Have you tried compressed air to just blow it out?? Usually the fan/heat sink/etc is close enough to the outside that a can of compressed air will get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

http://it.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/jsp/SUPPORTSECTION/discontinuedProductPage.do?service=IT&PRODUCT_ID=1056713&DISC_MODEL=1#0

with so patiently and love.